# Bookmarklet: Highlight web components

Tags: web-component, highlight, bookmarklet, shadow-dom, bookmarks

I have this bookmarklet code and it works with adding the border around the anchor tags:

```
javascript: (function () {
    var a = document.createElement('style'),
        b;
    document.head.appendChild(a);
    b = a.sheet;
    b.insertRule("a{box-shadow:2px 2px 0 0 #f00 !important;", 0);
})()
```

However, I am trying to highlight (put the border) around web components rending on the webpage. These web components use the shadow DOM.

I am trying to target the ones that have a specific HTML tag, for example `<orbi-button>`, `<orbi-modal>`, `<orbi-modal>`, etc. The goal is to display a border around the entire rendered component.

Here's the sample code of what the HTML looks like of the rendered component:

```
<orbi-button appearance="solid" color="blue" scale="m" href="" dir="ltr" hastext="" width="auto" orbi-hydrated="">
   button text here
    </orbi-button>
```

so I'm assuming something like `<orbi-*>` would target all the web components.

I'm a newbie for code and usually hack stuff together. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Only if shadowRoots are created with the `mode:"open"` setting can you access shadowRoots from the outside.

You can then *dive* into elements and shadowRoots with:

```
 const shadowDive = (
          el, 
          selector, 
          match = (m, r) => console.warn('match', m, r)
  ) => {
    let root = el.shadowRoot || el;
    root.querySelector(selector) && match(root.querySelector(selector), root);
    [...root.children].map(el => shadowDive(el, selector, match));
  }
```

Note that the global CSS you inject won't touch anything inside shadowRoots.

So you have to inject that `<style>` into **every** shadowRoot you find.

Comment: The code has two slight problems:

1. By using `root.querySelector()` instead `root.matches()`, the same element might be matched several times while recursing.

2. It seems, an element can have a `shadowRoot` as well as regular `children`. So recursion should be done for both.

My solution: `function shadowDive(el, selector, match = (e) => console.log('match', e)) { function go(e) { if (e.matches(selector)) match(e); for (c of e.children) go(c); if (e.shadowRoot) for (c of e.shadowRoot.children) go(c); } go(el); }`.

Comment: Probably better to post your code as Answer, so OP can mark it as the correct answer